# Let $B\in M_{n\times n}$ so that $B^{3}=0$ and let $I$ be the identity matrix the same format. Also $A=I-B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B\in M_{n\times n}$ so that $B^{3}=0$ and let $I$ be the identity matrix the same format. Also $A=I-B$

Prove that A is a regular matrix and express $A^{-1}$ via $I$ and $B$.

If $b\in R^{n}$ express the solution via $b$ and $B$

My idea was to consider 3 cases

1st case: $B=0$

2nd case: $B\neq 0$,$B^{2}=0$

3rd case: $B\neq 0$,$B^{2}\neq 0$,$B^{3}=0$

and to solve the equation $A=I-B$. In all three cases I get that $A=I$.
So $A^{-1} = I$ and I can write that like $1*I+0*B$

But I'm not sure if this is the right approach.
Could someone offer a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$(I-B^3)=(I-B)(I+B+B^2)$$

Comment: Sorry but how exactly does this hint help me?

Comment: @DraganZrilić Think harder and you'll realize it is *exactly* the solution to your problem...

Comment: Okay, I've figured out that $A^{-1}=I+B+B^{2}$ if A is a regular matrix. But I have not proven that A is a regular matrix, so I cannot make this claim. How would I go about proving that A is a regular matrix with the conditions that I have given?

Comment: If you have figured out that $\;A^{-1}=\;$ whatever, **that means** $\;A\;$ is regular...! Anyway, since $\;A\;$ is a **square** matrix, if $\;AH=I\;$ then *automatically* $\;A\;$ is regular and $\;AH=HA=I\;,\;\;A^{-1}=H\;$ .

Comment: Thank you for the explanation